# DBeaver - Auto increment ID field in Oracle 12c

Tags: database, oracle, dbeaver

I'm new with using DBeaver with Oracle and I'm trying to create an auto increment a PK field. I've been researching and can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

In 12c you have several options

**IDENTITY COLUMNS**

```
SQL> create table t ( id number generated always as identity ( start with 1 increment by 1 ) primary key, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t ( c2 ) values ( 1 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

        ID         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1

SQL>
```

Refer to this link for the different options on identity columns

[Identity Columns](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-identity-column/)

**SEQUENCES**

```
SQL> create sequence t_sq start with 1 increment by 1 ;

Sequence created.

SQL> create table t ( id number default t_sq.nextval primary key, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t ( c2 ) values ( 1 ) ;

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t ;

        ID         C2
---------- ----------
         1          1
```

As you can see above, you have either the option to use IDENTITY columns, or you can create a sequence and assign the nextval of the sequence to the column as default value.

Either case, you have an auto increment id as primary key.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a try but I'm assuming this means you there is no way through the GUI?